# How to create cakephp form with recursive models

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to create a form that uses an HABTM relationship.   The join table has fields that are foreign keys to another table. I need to enter data into one of these fields.  Is it even possible?

Example.

model1 (id, field1, field2)
model2 (id, field1, field2)
model3 (id, field1, field2)

joinmodel (foreign keys that join model1 and model2, but belongsto model3.

The form would have fields from model1 and model1 without issues, but the field for joinmodel->model1(field1) is what gets me.

I'm not sure this is perfectly clear what I'm trying to accomplish.  If this doesn't make sense I'll post my real model data.

Answer (score 0):

This I believe can be done, when declaring your form elements you would do the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model1');
echo $this->Form->input('Model2');
echo $this->Form->input('Model3');
echo $this->Form->input('field');
```

Then in the controller you'd do `$this->Model1->saveAll($this->data);`

[More info](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/how_do_i_add_multiple_categories_to_jobs_and_save_the_form_data)

Another way you could do it is save the model data in order let's say Model2 has a foreign key of model 1 and 3, then you'd save models 1 and 3 first, assign the IDs to the proper fields in Model2 and save Model2. Of course all in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you have related tables and you want to put in the form then you can put something like this.

```
$this->Form->input('Model1.0.field1');
$this->Form->input('Model1.0.field2');
$this->Form->input('Model2.0.field1');
$this->Form->input('Model2.0.field2');
```

If you 2nd row you can give

```
$this->Form->input('Model1.1.field1');
$this->Form->input('Model1.1.field2');
$this->Form->input('Model2.1.field1');
$this->Form->input('Model2.0.field2');
```

and so on...

Finally you can save all data in one shot by using

```
$this->Model->saveAll($this->data);
```

Where Model is your the main model in which view you're creating your form.
This will also apply all the model validation.

While saving in controller you can just use

`$this->Model1->saveAll($this->data);`